# throw user defined exception in single statement in java

Tags: java, exception

Recently i attended an interview. one of the questions asked in technical interview round is "how can you throw a user defined exception using single statement".
i wrote the code as

```
class MyException extends Exception{
public MyExeption(String err){
super(err);
}
class sample{
public static void main(String a[]){
throw new MyException("Error");
}
```

but he said that i used 2 statements 1 for throw statement and other for super() statement.
what is the answer. plese clear my doubt. thank you

Comment: This sounds like a nonsense question; what is a "user-defined exception" supposed to be?

Comment: User-defined Exception is an exception which is defined by the programmer by inheriting one of Exception & RuntimeExceptions which can have the behavior of predefined exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure that the interviewer was looking for you to extend `Exception` anonymously:

```
throw new Exception("Error") {
    // Here is what makes the exception user-defined.
    // You do not need to override anything, but if you want, you can:
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Here is your user-defined exception!";
    }
};
```

Comment: And if the interviewer did mean that, he's either being a bit stupid or a "clever d^^k" ... 'cos there's no good reason to write code like that.  There is no point whatsoever in creating / using an anonymous exception.

Comment: @StephenC Absolutely! There's no point in throwing anonymous exceptions.

Comment: Yeah, that's the only thing I could possibly think of, but that is so useless that I was having trouble believing it.

Comment: @chrylis Interviewers sometimes throw curveball at you, asking you do something that you've never tried in real life, and see if you can solve as a kind of a puzzle. I've heard about interviewers asking about the difference between `a[4]` and `4[a]` in C (there is none) simply to hear you explain pointer arithmetics. Their company may even have a policy where writing `4[a]` would see you fired on the spot.

Comment: The interviewer is also overlooking the implied `super()` call. And given his apparent 'thought' processes, why doesn't the `return` statement count as a statement?

Comment: @EJP You don't need a return statement if you get rid of `getMessage`, as I suggested in the comment. I put `getMessage` there only for an illustration. The call of `super` shouldn't count, though, because it's implicit.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Oh, I'm aware interviewers do stupid things. The fact that frat boys get drunk and do stupid things doesn't excuse them, either.

Answer (score 2):

Literally, the question asks to **throw**. Not to declare & throw.

```
throw new MyUserDefinedException("It was declared elsewhere.");
```

If you want to declare & throw, that's what the other answer said. Of course this is complete crap code with no purpose. I would penalize or fire somebody, who used this kind of approach in real work.

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("BS interview question, take another job."){};
```

It also doesn't work, over RMI :(  The worst thing is, how many days of debugging ($1000s..) it will take to uncover it again, if some twit ever writes this bug for you.

They may be testing your Java understanding, but it seems likely these clowns don't actually know how to use/ what to do with Java themselves.

My interview questions ask actual real business questions. They can be highly challenging.

I don't look for idiots who can do stupid pointless things within the language idiom, I look for people who can solve not-easy problems within a typical business application.